# Show that the series $∑a_nb_n$ is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

Suppose that $\sum a_n$ is a convergent series, with $a_n>0$, and
suppose that $(b_n)\ n∈\mathbb N$, $b_n>0$ is a bounded sequence of positive numbers.

Show that the series $∑a_nb_n$ is convergent.

*All summations are between $n=0$ and $∞$

Comment: Hint: $\sum_n a_nb_n \leq M \sum_n a_n$ where $M$ is the bound on $b_n$.

Answer (score 5):

Say $|b_n| \le M$ for all $M$. Since $a_n$ and $b_n >0$ for all $n$ then 
$$\sum_{k=1}^N a_nb_n \le M \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \le M \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k<\infty.$$

So the partial sums are bounded, and they are increasing. Hence the partial sums converge.